# Pandas: Rearranging columns after merging 2 data frames without re indexing

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two data frames which I later merge into one.
For the first data frame **dfm** I have a dictionary which I'm writing to the data frame but I get the error

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

After searching SO I used index=[0]. But now when I merge the other data frame I get two indexes with 0 and NaN values in the second data frame.

1st data frame:

```
col=['Target_Tab', 'Source_Tab', 'exp']
dfm = pd.DataFrame(s, columns = ['Target_Tab', 'Source_Tab', 'exp'],index=[0])
print(dfm)
```

Output:

```
          Target_Tab             Source_Tab                  exp
0          employees             employee              emp_id  =  old_emp_id
```

2nd data frame

```
col=['Source_Col', 'Target_Col']
dft = pd.concat([pd.Series(v.split(), name=k) for k, v in d1.items()], axis=1).fillna('')[col]

print(dft)
```

Output:

```
    Source_Col            Target_Col
0           id            emp_id
1        last_name       l_name
2       first_name      f_name
3            email           email
4     phone_number    phone_number
5         JOB_DATE        JOB_DATE
```

After Merging:

```
dfa = pd.concat([dfm, dft],sort=False)
dfa
```

Output:

```
         Source_Tab          Source_Col         Target_Tab       Target_Col  \
0              employee           NaN             employees             NaN   
0                  NaN           id                      NaN            emp_id   
1                  NaN      last_name                  NaN          l_name   
2                  NaN      first_name                  NaN          f_name   
3                  NaN           email                  NaN           email   
4                  NaN    phone_number                  NaN    phone_number   
5                  NaN        JOB_DATE                  NaN        JOB_DATE   


               expr  
0   emp_id  =  old_emp_id  
0                     NaN  
1                     NaN  
2                     NaN  
3                     NaN  
4                     NaN  
5                     NaN
```

How do I get one [0] index so that the two dataframes [0] index values are on the same line i.e something like this in the beginning.

```
      Source_Tab     Source_Col   Target_Tab   Target_Col   expr

0     employee      id           employees     emp_id      emp_id  = old_emp_id
1       NaN        last_name      NaN          l_name      Nan
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I added the parameter `axis=1` in `dfa = pd.concat([dfm, dft],sort=False,axis=1)`
Referred [axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for outer join

```
import pandas as pd

s=["a","b","c"]
col=['Target_Tab', 'Source_Tab', 'exp']
df=pd.DataFrame(s).T
df.columns=col
print(df)
col2=['Source_Col', 'Target_Col']
Source_Col=[1,2,3,4,5]
Target_Col=[1,2,3,4,5]
df2=pd.DataFrame([Source_Col,Target_Col]).T
df2.columns=col2
print(df2)
df.join(df2, how='outer')
```